# Can I make a certain part of a treeview scrollable in PyGTK (PyGObject)

Tags: treeview, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject, scrollable

I am using PyGObject to create a GUI, which makes it a little hard for me to understand the C-based documentation that the original project provides. I am looking for a way to make a certain range of rows scrollable in a treeview.

Is there any way I can do this, by using a well-known method or even trying to Frankenstein it together?

This is what my gui looks like so far:

[Debugger GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cULwb.png)

I would like for the line number column to only scroll vertically and the actual code column to scroll both ways. (As an aside, I wouldn't mind if the top row stayed static too).

This is how I am creating the treeview currently:

```py
import gi
import os

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango
from CLProg import CLProg


class CodeViewer(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, data_list, possible_lines):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self)
        self.data_list = data_list
        self.possible_lines = possible_lines

        # Initial Values
        self.linecount = 1
        self.background = Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.fontdesc_code = Pango.FontDescription("mono 10")
        self.fontdesc_line = Pango.FontDescription("mono 8")

        self.list_store = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, Gdk.RGBA)
        self.update_vals()

    def update_vals(self):
        for item in range(len(self.data_list)):
            if item % 2 == 0:
                self.background = Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, .1)
            else:
                self.background = Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0)
            if str(self.linecount) in self.possible_lines:
                self.background = Gdk.RGBA(0, 1, 0, 0.2)
            self.list_store.append((self.linecount, self.data_list[item]) + (self.background,))
            self.linecount += 1

        self.list_view = Gtk.TreeView(self.list_store)

        self.line_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.line_renderer.set_property('foreground', 'white')
        self.line_renderer.set_property('font-desc', self.fontdesc_line)
        self.line_renderer.set_alignment(True, False)
        self.line_renderer.set_property('background-rgba', Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, .6))
        line_column_title = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Line", self.line_renderer, text=0)
        self.list_view.append_column(line_column_title)

        code_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        code_renderer.set_property('font-desc', self.fontdesc_code)
        code_column_title = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("", code_renderer, text=1)
        self.list_view.append_column(code_column_title)
        code_column_title.add_attribute(code_renderer, "background-rgba", 2)
        self.pack_start(self.list_view, True, True, 0)


class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Homogeneous Debugger")
        self.set_default_size(1000, 900)
        self.set_border_width(15)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_gravity(Gdk.Gravity.CENTER)

        # HEADER BAR FOR MAIN WINDOW
        header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        header_bar.set_show_close_button(True)
        header_bar.props.title = "Debugger"
        self.set_titlebar(header_bar)
        select_button = Gtk.Button("Confirm")
        header_bar.pack_end(select_button)

        # CLProg object which contains Files -> Functions -> Variables
        prog = CLProg()
        prog.locate_function("main_func")
        prog.open_c()

        # Creating the specialized Gtk boxes
        code_viewer = CodeViewer(prog.filelist, prog.possible_lines)

        # Declares scroll windows for boxes
        vscroll_code = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()

        # Set scroll policy
        vscroll_code.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

        # Packs objects in scrollable spaces
        vscroll_code.add(code_viewer)

        self.add(vscroll_code)

def main():
    window = Main()
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help or ideas on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you don't have to use the C documentation — there is Python documentation here: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

Comment: Isn't [GtkSource](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4) better for displaying code?